# Silverlight RIA Services OutputCache for Invoke operations does not working

Tags: caching, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, outputcache

I can successfully get OutputCache working for Query operation, but I cannot make cache working for my Invoke operation, even if I mark is as HasNoSideEffect=true (HTTP GET).

Here is code of my service:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class MyDomainService:DomainService
{
    [OutputCache(OutputCacheLocation.Server, 60, UseSlidingExpiration = true)]
    public IQueryable<MyEntity1> GetMyItems(string parameter)
    {
        var res = new List<MyEntity1>();
        var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var newItem = new MyEntity1();
            newItem.Id = i;
            newItem.InstantiatedTime = dtNow;
            newItem.ParameterValue = parameter;
            res.Add(newItem);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return res.AsQueryable();
    }

    [System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.Invoke(HasSideEffects = false)]
    [OutputCache(OutputCacheLocation.Any, 60, UseSlidingExpiration = true)]
    public IEnumerable<string> MyInvokeOperation(string parameter)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();
        var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var newItem = i.ToString();
            newItem += dtNow.ToString() + parameter;
            res.Add(newItem);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return res;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyEntity1
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime InstantiatedTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ParameterValue{get;set;}
}
```

And here are results in network traffic:

[image: Network traffic image from IE10]

As you can see for Query second execution takes less than a second, while for Invoke it takes 3 seconds again.

How to make RIA OutputCache work for Invoke operation?